# How to get all records within a specific group of a GROUP BY result in pure SQL

Tags: sql, impala

Do you know the best way to get all records within a specific group of a `GROUP BY` results in pure SQL (by index if it's possible)?

Update:

```
SELECT col1, col2 from my_table GROUP BY col1, col2 where col1 = 123
```

Comment: Um...use `HAVING` ?

Comment: A JOIN perhaps. Why dont you show us some sample data and expected result

Comment: Give more context , sample data , what have you tried till now?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question do not post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: I have edited - I have the results set  - I need to get all results in each grouping without leaving SQL if possible?

Comment: Can I use the HAVING by group index?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, you used the GROUP BY clause to group your data by particular column data. If you have a specific value you would like to pull by using that column's data then a WHERE clause would be your best bet at getting the data you're looking to get

Comment: yes but I need to use the WHERE on a specific group result, without leaving SQL if possible?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, if I understand your question properly is to use `HAVING` clause in your query.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (col1 INT, col2 INT);
GO

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,2),(3,4),(123,1),(123,2);
GO

SELECT col1,col2 FROM my_table GROUP BY col1,col2 HAVING col1=123
GO

DROP TABLE my_table
GO
```